# How to set default picklist value on Custom combobox using LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-combobox, child-to-parent

Child lwc JS :

```
setSelection() {
const selectedItems = this.getSelectedItems();
let selection = '';
if (selectedItems.length < 1) {
  selection = this.placeholder;
  this.selectedOptions = [];
}  else {
  selection = selectedItems.map((selected) => selected.label).join(', ');
  this.selectedOptions = this.getSelectedItems();
}
this.selectedItems = selection;
this.isVisible = this.selectedOptions && this.selectedOptions.length > 0;
console.log('selection',selection);

  getSelectedItems() {
return this.currentOptions.filter((item) => item.selected);
```

Child lwc HTML :

```
             <input
            class="slds-combobox__input multi-select-combobox__input"
            aria-controls="multi-pick-list-dropdown-items"
            role="textbox"
            type="text"
            value={selectedItems}
            required={required}
            disabled={isDisabled}
            readonly
          />
```

SelectedItems is an array , and in the parent HTML

```
 <c-multi-select-combobox
                                                    label="Value"
                                                    name="options01"
                                                    selected-items={acc.Value__c}
                                                    options={picklistValues.data.values}
                                                    onchange={handleValueChange} >
```

Output:

[image]

the issue i'm facing is in initialization the combobox doesn't display the value selected by default . I.E : *Value__c* is a text field it contains *Clos* as value , the combobox should display clos selected - Any help ?

Comment: Hello , this seems quite unclear. Is it the html `<input>` element that renders  as the dropdown ?

Comment: yes , its a dropdown list and i want it to get the value which correspond to value__c

Comment: okay. is there i specific reason you are not using the inbuilt `<lightning-combobox>`. I think it makes all of this very easy

Comment: its a custom combobox , because i need to select multilple values .. the issue here is that the  *SelectedItems* is an array and the *acc.value__c* is a string